# How to install older Android SDK in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, api, sdk

I'm working at the moment at a simple app in eclipse for android. Just receiving and sending data, and using the camera API.

I've set the minSDKversion to 8, because I think that has the widest user base. But at the beginning of the project eclipse was asking me which target SDK version I would use, and because I had just one installed (the latest 4.0.3) I've took this.

Now I'm asking me if it wouldn't be wiser to install a lower SDK, like Android 2.2, because it would be not that big (compared to the 4.0.3) and my app would not have included all the fancy new features, which are not used in any way?! Or is this complete nonsense I'm talking here, and just should take my 4.0.3 SDK? When not, how can I install a lower version? `Help -> SDK Manager` is not showing old SDKs...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a very helpful link that will probably answer your question: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

Basically, open up the Android SDK manager and it should give you a list of packages that you can install! From there you can choose old SDKs!

Comment: Thanks. But that don't really answers my question. My app is running on 2.2 devices well (with all functions). So should I use the 2.2 SDK in eclipse for creating and building my app, or is this euqal to the 4.0.3 SDK (in terms of performance, because I don't use 4.0.3 features)?

Comment: There is no performance difference as far as writing a 2.2 targeted app using 2.2 vs. 4.0.3 only features - I have no source for this statement so if someone wants to correct me or expand on this than I encourage them to.

Comment: I think you're confused on what the SDK is. There aren't really multiple SDK versions. The different packages simply support the different features of Android versions. There is only one SDK. When you install the 2.2 package then you have access to everything that Android 2.2 encompasses (including functions that may be deprecated in later versions)

Comment: The OP may want to review this page which explains the difference between min and target sdk: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

Comment: thanks to you all. i thought about this a second time and what you are talking makes sense. my app can't be "really" affected (in terms of performance or size) of the sdk because if so the sdk has to be packed into my app... which will blow the app up to like 150mb... ok, now i got it. thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

hey i faced the same issue as yours 
usually while updating due to this error , it is unable to fetch the older SDKs 
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml, reason: File not found

This is how you can fix it :
1) Go to Window > AndroidSDK Manager
2) select tools> options 
3) set the proxy (if u r sitting behind proxy)
4) in checkboxes check Obsolete option (in Android SDK Manager)
5) go to Packages > reload (in Android SDK Manager)

This worked for me 
In case you are using windows7 . 
Go to Android SDK Manager location > right click > Run as Administrator

Best Regards,
Ashwani kumar

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with this also.  I tried all of the things listed in the other answers here and nothing worked.  I went into Tools/Options (in the Android SDK Manager) and checked "Force https:// sources to be fetched using http://" and reloaded and the older APIs magically appeared.

Answer (score 0):

if u want  minSDKversion from its maxSDKversion 
1.select maxSDKversion and delete all old pakages .
2. after doing it sdk manager will show all its older versions .
3. select required version and install all packages again.
 :) :)
it worked for me ..  just try .