# Xamarin-Studio Android Form Designer: Android Version not installed

Tags: c#, android, monodevelop, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Recently, I took an interest in Xamarin, a system used for running C# code on both mobile and stationary devices. After setting up my Android environment using the Xamarin Studio ( a modified version of the popular IDE MonoDevelop), I had a few problems which I managed to fix, this being one that I've spent some time working on to no avail.

**Problem**

After creating an application, and opening the Main.axml file where the Layout of the app is stored, I get this message instead.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cjsN.png

Here is the XML code associated with the form.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Obviously, this is a problem, as I can't design Android forms with this message. One notable thing is that it says 'Android 4.4 (v10) on the top panel. I am using the most recent SDK from the Android site (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), so I am confused as to why it is telling me that the Android Version is not installed.

**A few things I've tried**

When designing forms in Xamarin, it gives you a sample emulated system to build your forms off of, in order to determine the size of the screen and other possible associated variables. It gives you the option between various Nexus devices where you can build your forms. I tried switching devices, but I still receive the error message.

I've re-installed the SDK and also done a fresh install of Xamarin itself. These solutions helped with a few of my *other* problems, but this one has been persistent.

**Conclusion**

Why is Xamarin giving me this message? What is the problem? Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Your problem may be that Android 4.4 hasn't been released yet, so it is still buggy. Try using a different version, preferably 4.3

Comment: You said you reinstalled everything. While reinstalling, have you by any chance, let the Xamarin Studio setup kit install the Android SDK **for you** instead of finding an already installed one ? Furthermore, and let it be known that I simply adore Xamarin (I'm using it for iOS development where I'm stuck with their IDE), since you're developing for Android and not for iOS you are allowed to do it on a Windows machine. I would suggest (at least until they get all of their bugs fixed) using Visual Studio instead, and also making sure that VS is installed when installing Xamarin Studio

Comment: In case it wasn't clear enough, my suggestions are: Use VS, not XS and reinstall things in **this** order: 1. Visual Studio , 2. Xamarin Studio and 3. let the Xamarin Studio setup discover the lack of Android SDK while it's installing Xamarin Studio itself and let it install it for you. Already having VS would not make it necessary to reinstall VS, but installing VS after XS would make it necessary to uninstall XS and the reinstall it after VS

Comment: @EduardDumitru Indeed, I *did* let it install Android SDK for me. I didn't think it would cause this much of a problem for me. Would you care to elaborate on this? I don't think I am permitted to use VS as I am only using their Free plan.

Comment: No no.. I tried to make it clearer in my second comment. Please excuse my clumsy ways. It's good that you did that. It would've been worse not doing so. That leaves me with saying: I have no clue, Hope someone who uses that version of Android SDK + Xamarin sees your question !  And the VS stuff is just a hunch. The things I'm certain of is that VS is not as bad a **text** editor as is XS. I'm sorry I had forgotten about their new pricing plans. Originally they would not do this. I suspect you will be moving to Indie (like I did) pretty soon anyway, since you have an absurd app footprint limit

Comment: You didn't used to be with the free version. As they are now holding hands I doubt very much that has changed. You used to be able, and may still, to try it out with VS, but it was time limited. May have changed. But @EduardDumitru, I think you meant your dev-ing *on* iOS. VS can be used for iOS with purchased Xamarin.

Comment: @BobbyDigital And as for Android dev? I didn't think that you could dev android apps using VS without paying for it.

Comment: @BobbyDigital I wish that were generally true :). It is if you don't have the Indie plan like I do. And if you're just a passionate indie like I am, and you don't make a lot of money out of developing with Xamarin, then the Business and Enterprise plans are absurdly overpriced (but that's not their problem, it's mine :), I admit). Furthermore, the VS - XS+Xcode TCP/IP link was really really buggy at the time I gave it a trial. Needless to say: They're great for what they have achieved and they're a handful of people

Comment: You'll be paying for the Indie plan sooner than you think (if you don't intend to quit).So it's not just the lack of VS that's going to convince you.The fact that you can't create View Controllers yet didn't allow you to extend past the app size limit (which is **very** small, believe me). So, if you'll be having I dunno, 3 view controllers, one WS stub, and a few resources you're already past the limit and you **can't even** test things out on the emulator. I really think you can go with Indie and have VS support for Xamarin (MonoDroid not MonoTouch). I think you don't need Business for that.

Comment: @EduardDumitru that's right. For the C#-ers, it's (VS) integration is a great selling point for Xamarin. I believe Xamarin is a bit cheaper overall now because the deal is for both Android and iOS. I don't share your adoration of Xamarin. It was fairly clunky IMHO. I switched to Android, even being a lover of C#, and it seemed to be more productive and better performing.

Comment: So, now that we've had our little tea party, what is the issue here? Do I need to reinstall my APK/SDK?

Comment: I am an Indie registered developer for iOS only. If I want Android also it's another story (another Indie license, which I could've bundled together with my current one and get a small discount) but no, they have separate licenses (each costing the same) for iOS, Android and Mac. They do allow you to develop open source (not AppStore) Mac applications for free.

Comment: I guess not. What I would suggest is writing them an e-mail about it (with a link to this actual question BTW) and then, after receiving an answer sharing it with the rest of the tea enthusiasts :). I really think Miguel and Nat should know about these troubles (if they're not watching us already, drinking beer :) )

Comment: Will do, thanks for the suggestions, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this was weird to figure out. Here's what I did.

**The Fix**

I was using the Android 4.4 (KitKat) SDK because that was the most recent SDK. After searching around for a bit, I finally found a conclusion, mainly through trial-and-error and a the help of a few people. As of this point, I guess that Xamarin Studio is not compatible/doesn't run well with Android 4.4. All I had to do to fix it was re-install packages from Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean) and then use the SDK with 4.3 packages instead of the new 4.4 packages (You can find an explanation on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296302/how-to-install-older-android-sdk-in-eclipse)). I'm sure this isn't a lasting bug, as eventually Xamarin Studio will be compatible with Android 4.4.

If anybody is ever having problems with this in the future, the solution here is fairly simple. Simply use an SDK from a previous version.