# Where can I locate older versions of the Android SDK for Jelly Bean 4.3?

Tags: android, sdk, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm having a bug with Xamarin. The bug I'm having is in regards to the Android SDK, and to fix it I believe that I need an older version of the Android SDK, which I'm having trouble locating. I know that there have been posts such as [this Quora post](http://www.quora.com/Android-Development/Where-can-one-get-old-versions-of-Android-SDKs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296302/how-to-install-older-android-sdk-in-eclipse), but I'm not sure if the newer versions are excluded from this or if I'm just not guessing the address correctly.

Anyways, what is the easiest way to correctly obtain older versions of the Android SDK, specifically for Jelly Bean 4.3? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one version of the Android SDK. Revisions just update some features, such as ADB or the building system for making Android apps. However, you can download more packages in your SDK installation, such as Android 4.3 or Android 2.1. To do that:

Go into the path you downloaded the SDK into. Then open `SDK Manager.exe`. When it loads and refreshes the packages list, it will display a list of packages you can download. If you want to download the 4.3 packages, just click the checkbox next to the Android 4.3 - API level 18 item.