# AlarmManager stops working in Android 4.4.2 (using SetExact())

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm setting in my code an alarm to go off in specific time.
The alarm mechanism works great on SDK < 19, but on 19 the alarms aren't fired.
Here is the code where I set the alarm :

```
public void SetAlarm(Context context, Long executionTime)
{

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReciever.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Only one alarm can live, so cancel previous.
    am.cancel(pi);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, executionTime, pi);
    } else {
        setAlarmFromKitkat(am, executionTime, pi);
    }
}
```

Since I'm setting the alarm using a `Service` I use `GetApplicationContext()` as the context.

The `onReceive()` code :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    for (SchedulerListener listener : listeners) {
        listener.fetchAndRebuildNotification();
    }
}
```

Here is the declaration of the `BroadcastReceiver` :

```
<receiver 
        android:name="com.SagiL.myAppName.BroadCastReceivers.AlarmReciever" />
```

The callback runs a method in a service (which is still alive when the alarm supposed to fire, notice it doesn't starts one).

This whole thing is a `library` which is used in my app, and there I declare the receiver the same way.

Sometimes the alarm do fires once, but mostly it doesn't fire at all.

Has anyone experienced such a thing ?
I can't believe it's common to SDK 19 since a lot of apps are using `AlarmManager` and they will break too if it is common.

Comment: Are you sure that the `AlarmManager` doesn't fire at all? can you ensure that it doesn't fire also in range of 10 minutes? Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20352528/2075420

Comment: It doesn't fire in any range ... it looks like it get unregistered.  And when using `setExact()` there should be no range at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my application. I found out that using `0` ad the id in `getBroadcast(...);` didn't work very well and caused numerous problems.

Try changing the `id` from `0` to the alarm's real id.

From:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

To:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: How do I get the real ID ?

Comment: You can set it yourself to whatever you want, make sure every unique alarm have a unique id.

Comment: I'm always replacing one alarm with the other, I never 'hold' 2 alarms together, so it's always the same `PI` and same everything, should I still set different ID to each alarm ?

Comment: That what I thought too. But only changing the ID helped me cancel and replace the alarms.

Comment: Can you please more be clear ? What do you mean changing the ID? random ID ? What do you mean cancel and replace ?

Comment: When I wanted to cancel an alarm, it was just an example. I don't mean a random ID, I mean that each type of alarm should have it's own id. If you have 2 different types of alarms, one for setting action A and one for action B. Each of them should have it's own ID.

Comment: As I mentioned, I use only 1 type of alarm, so using 0 as ID shouldn't be any different than any other number. Meaning this is probably not the solution for the problem.

Comment: The fact is that using 0 and using any other number does make a difference. It's not documented anywhere but based on my experience, using 0 as request code is almost never a good idea.

Comment: I use other id´s than 0, also it does not work correct on android 4.4.2. Must be a buck.....

Answer (score 7):

It´s a late answer, but may help. In Android KitKat 4.4.xx a battery manager is integrated (my device: Huawei Ascend Mate 7). There is an option to kill background process and services of an app in the battery manager. Don´t know if the options are named similar to the german options, so just try:

1. go to settings
2. select save energy
3. select detailed power consumption
4. select Screen off: perform further
5. enable Your app

It sounds simple, but that exactly was my problem. On Samsung Galaxy S3 with ICS everything worked like a charm. But bought a new device, the huawei, with Android 4.4.2, and suddenly my apps alarms didn´t work. After checking the system, I detected that option, enabled my app and now everything is fine. Not everything is a programming answer :) .

### UPDATE

Since this answer was made, a lot happened in Android. For everybody with a similar problem: Since update to Marshmallow, there are two problems: first one is like described above, the second one is the doze mode:

[Optimitzing Doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

Some devices, like my Huawei Ascend Mate 7, using both energy saving methods. So it isn´t enough to do what is described above. Also, you have to whitelist the app and use the new `alarmManager` methods `setAllowWhileIdle()`, `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` and `setAlarmClock()` .

### Possible Problems

By whitelisting your app, you have to tell this the user. You can do it with a simple information at starting your app, for example a `AlertDialog` and/or you can use `ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS` `intent` to start the whitelisting screen. But be aware of this Action, because like reported from some developers, Google can suspend an app from playstore that is calling this action.

`setAlarmClock`should also work, but if you do this, an alarm clock icon is on the top.

### Testing

I have made some tests with that new documented doze mode and found out, that it usually works. But without whitelisting, the app falling to standby and ´alarmManager´ does not fire anymore, also not with that new methods. I tested it over night and the app is send to standby within about one hour. At a normal situation at day, where the user is active and often moves his device, it works without whitelisting.