# Android Services: START_STICKY does not work on Kitkat

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I am using services in an application to listen for how many times the user presses his/her power button. The implementation was working fine on all devices. But when I tested the app on the Android Kitkat, I noticed something wrong.

As soon as I swipe the application away from the recents apps, the application no longer listens for the power button.

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
public class Receiver extends Service {

    Notification notification;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
    NotificationManager manager;
    PendingIntent toOpen;
    Intent intent;
    private BroadcastReceiver POWER_BUTTON = new Powerbuttonrecceiver();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        registerReceiver(POWER_BUTTON, filter);
        startNotify();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        unregisterReceiver(POWER_BUTTON);
        dismissNotification();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void startNotify(){
        manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher_drop;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Service activated";
        CharSequence tickerContent = "Service is now on. You can press your power button and the app will listen to it. Tap to turn this feature off";
        intent = new Intent(Receiver.this, Options.class);
        toOpen = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setContentTitle(tickerText)
        .setContentText(tickerContent)
        .setSmallIcon(icon)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentIntent(toOpen)
        .build();
        manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    public void dismissNotification(){
        manager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }

}
```

As one can notice I am using a notification to signify that the service is active. The thing that confuses me is that after the swipe from the recents app the notification still remains, what is inactive is the `BroadcastReceiver`? or is that false.

In the app's `onDestroy` I have not called in any functions to register or unregister as well as stop the service. Once again, this problem is only seen in Android KitKat. Please if you guys know whats happening. Do help :)

**UPDATE**: I also noticed with the `Play Music` on Kitkat, when I swipe it away from the recents app the music stops. Is this a bug on Kitkat? But the sound/mediaplayer services on `SoundCloud` works even when swiped away from the recents app.

**UPDATE:**
Logged as [Issue 63618](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63618) on android issue tracker. 
Read issue comments for more details.

Comment: When you swipe away the application, you are effectively destroying the service ... isn't it ?

Comment: I have not specifically called out any functions to destroy the service. As I said before the application works fine on earlier Android API's other than Kitkat @MadhurAhuja

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636330/start-sticky-does-not-work-on-android-kitkat

Comment: Why not to register the receiver in Manifest?

Comment: Y u no startForeground?

Comment: You already add a notification for your process in the notif. bar. Why not mark your service as foreground with startForeground and same notification, explicitly declaring this service as important for your application?

Comment: disregard that, startForeground won't help you, sorry

Comment: I just tested it with our newly developed app and yes, this is really happening, so +1 for the question and I have no answer!

Comment: I've update issue id in question. Also, Have you tried running service in a separate process ?

Comment: @S.D. separate process meaning ??

Comment: @user2247689 In Manifest, you can configure a service to run in its own process.

Comment: @S.D. did you mean to declare the `android:stopWithTask="false"` sort of attribute or, `android:isolatedProcess="true"` ??

Comment: @user2247689 read the documentation for [`android:process=""`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) manifest tag.

Comment: See answer (with working solution!) here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21157035/624109

Answer (score 7):

Seems that this is a bug present in `Android 4.4`, got around it with the following:

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            this.getClass());
    restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +1000, restartServicePI);

}
```

So this is a method that is overridden in the `Service` class itself. The reason that I am using the `AlarmManager` is so that `Kitkat` does not kill my service.

Comment: SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +1000 may not be enough, in case of failure try longer delays, for example 2000ms

Comment: Seems onTaskRemoved is only good for restarting after swipe, but sometimes system stops app in background and "onTaskRemoved" is not called then!

Comment: Wow you really saved me!

Comment: @powder366   where they are actually restarting service ?

Comment: This does not work if you force quit app from Settings.

Comment: Start the service as a separate process if you want that. And also your service should also have a start sticky flag.

Comment: @Rakeeb  Alarm Manager never triggers the service for me somehow. (Android 4.4.4).

Answer (score 1):

I have this solution that works perfectly.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
     startService(new Intent(yourcontext, YourService.class));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is still an open bug for KK,

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63793

Comment: how are other apps getting around this ?

Comment: Thats depends on developer to developer. I think the way you are thinking also good, but you will gwt better performance if you try to resume it after few second.

Answer (score 0):

try my solution: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29727904/3811419)

this trick will restart your service everytime user close service from both task manager and force close from settings, i hope this will help you too

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to restart the service then call a alam manger to start the reciver like this,

Manifest is,

```
         <service
            android:name=".BackgroundService"
            android:description="@string/app_name"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="Notification" />
        <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="REFRESH_THIS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

IN Main Activty start alarm manger in this way,

```
String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(alarm);

        Intent intent = new Intent("REFRESH_THIS");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 123456789, intent, 0);

        int type = AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP;
        long interval = 1000 * 50;

        am.setInexactRepeating(type, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pi);
```

this will call reciver and reciver is,

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;

        System.out.println("Alarma Reciver Called");

        if (isMyServiceRunning(this.context, BackgroundService.class)) {
            System.out.println("alredy running no need to start again");
        } else {
            Intent background = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
            context.startService(background);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context, Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        if (services != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < services.size(); i++) {
                if ((serviceClass.getName()).equals(services.get(i).service.getClassName()) && services.get(i).pid != 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this Alaram reciver calls once when android app is opened and when app is closed.SO the service is like this,

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
    private String LOG_TAG = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        LOG_TAG = "app_name";
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "service created");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onStartCommand");
        //ur actual code
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Wont be called as service is not bound
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onTaskRemoved");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroyed");
    }
}
```