# KitKat: Service is null after exiting main activity

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service and I need to check if it's still running after some time from a static context. 
*[I noticed this happens only on Android KitKat]*

What I did:

My service:

```
public class Servizio extends Service {

   public static Service servizio;

   [...Other things...]

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   servizio = this;
      scheduleMyAlarmToDoSomethingAfterSomeTime();

   }

[...Other things...]
}
```

Then I launch the service from the main Activity in *onCreate*:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    [...]
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ServizioUtility.toggleService(this, true);
    [...]
}
```

Then I check if it's null after a minute (with an alarm receiver whose alarm was launched by the service. Note that the receiver works fine and the following code is called):

```
if (Servizio.servizio!=null) {// FIXME
    [...]
    //THIS IS NOT CALLED IN THE 2ND SCENARIO
}
```

There are 2 scenario:

1. I run the activity, wait for the alarm to be launched and *Servizio.servizio* is not null.
2. I run the activity, "kill" it using the [image] , wait for the alarm receiver to be called, *Servizio.servizio* is now null. Note that the service, on the other hand, is still running (checked from Settings->App->Running menu).

What's happening in the 2nd scenario?

Comment: See similar question (with solution) http://stackoverflow.com/q/20636330/624109

Comment: Service may appear to be running in Settings->Apps->Running, but it's actually not running. You can check by having service write a file to SD or actually check running processes. Its not running.

Comment: Yes, it appears but it isn't, in fact the service singleton is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out this is an issue with Android KitKat, if you want to check it out:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63793

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63618

Answer (score 2):

My simple workaround:

It sets the alarm with a 1 sec delay and stops the service by calling stopForeground().

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MessageHandlerService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(ACTION_REFRESH);
        serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis()+1000, PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, serviceIntent, 0)); //1 sec delay
        stopForeground(true); 
    }
}
```