# Application process getting killed in Android KitKat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

My application has got two services, `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`. `ServiceA` is a foreground service, `ServiceB` will be started when the device's screen is on and will be stopped when the device's screen is off.

These two services are collecting information, which we cannot afford to loose. But, on Android 4.4*, when the device's screen is turned off for a while and then turned back on, I can notice 0 processes and `ServiceA` running in the running section.

I've seen the reports on this version, where they claim that this scenario appears when the user swipes out our application from recent tasks. But, I'm noticing this when the screen is turned off for a while.

Note that `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` returns sticky and also, `ServiceA` is a foreground service.

Any definition will be very helpful.

Comment: Post code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Any service, with OnStartCommand returning sticky would recreate this problem. Especially Nexus 5.

Comment: Had a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636330/start-sticky-does-not-work-on-android-kitkat-edit-and-jelly-bean