# Add flags to incoming broadcasts

Tags: java, android

I need to listen for Install, Updates and Remove broadcasts via a `BroadcastReceivers`, here is the definition:

```
<receiver android:name=".InstallReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now, Is it possible to add `Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND` flags to these incoming intents? because in android KitKat receivers affect to foreground services due to bug which reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636330/start-sticky-does-not-work-on-android-kitkat-edit-and-jelly-bean/20681898#20681898).

Any ideas on how to add this flag to incoming broadcasts?

Comment: Share the solution if you've found the work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are welcome to call `addFlags()` on the `Intent`, it will not have any effect. Only the flags added by the broadcaster matter, and you are not the broadcaster.

Comment: Oops, can you please check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055454/destroy-foreground-notification-when-the-service-get-killed