# Services stops after some instance

Tags: android

I am implementing an app kind of an app tracker which requires to run the service all the time in background. So the service is called when application is opened and it stops when stopself() is called. Service also consists of a thread which runs all the time. It used to run perfect. But from last few days it stops after sometime. When coming to my app's ui after some task the service stops!
Can anyone suggest me any solution?

```
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.e("SERVICE","started");
        if(intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) 
        {
            day=intent.getExtras().getInt("day")+5;
            Toast.makeText(this, "day" +day, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            apps=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("apps");
            items=apps.size();
            timer=intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("timer");
            Run[] a=new Run[items];
            t=new Thread[items];

            for(int i=0;i<items;i++)
            {
               int sec=0;
               app=apps.get(i).toString();
               time=timer.get(i);
               a[i]=new Run(app, time,sec);
               Log.e("APPTIME",app+ " "+time);
               t[i]=new Thread(a[i]);
               t[i].start();
            }

        }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

Comment: What does your `onStartCommand` look like?

Comment: in my service i have implemented a class Run extens Runnable. My onstartcommand instantiates an object of Run!

Comment: What are you returning from your `onStartCommand`?  Add the code to your question.

Comment: use startService() call in your onDestroy() method of service so service will never stop untill your not uninstalling the application

Comment: But my service is passed some data (parameters) from the activity. So simple start service isn't enough. So in that cause how to restart service with same data passed from the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implementing foreground service. [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

Foreground service displays notification and is never stopped until you want.

Implement this code snippet in your service's onCreate

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion. But is there any other way because my app shows notification when its task gets complete.

Comment: yo can dismiss notification as your tasks get completed. If you dont want your service to get stopped in any condition, this is the way.

Comment: well it shows notification to ask the user whether to continue the task when a day is completed ! so in this case what can be done?

Comment: you just show notification like "MYApp service is running" or any message.

Comment: Ohk so throughout its running process the notification is present. But then how to alert the user to input details when the day gets complete with the same notification? From the user's point of view it might be the notification of "Running service".

Comment: ya .. yo got it. Notification you get when music player is playing music which means service needs to run always.

Comment: But then how to alert the user to input details when the day gets complete with the same notification?

Comment: you can start your activity to get inputs from user when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should start your service as [STICKY_SERVICE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY)

[Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService) for starting as STICKY

Thread for [START_STICKY and START_NOT_STICKY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9093271/1008278)

You should consider [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20636330/1008278), if you are working on Android KitKat

Comment: When i used start sticky it gives me null intent! And since i am checking this condition if(intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) the service isn't restarted.