# How to restart Background service getting killed on redmi phone

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have a service that should run in background.

I have applied solution from given link

[START_STICKY does not work on Android KitKat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636330/start-sticky-does-not-work-on-android-kitkat-edit-and-jelly-bean)

I am able to restart the service on all phones having android os jelly bean or kitkat.

But on Redmi (android os version 4.3)  phone my service is still getting killed when I remove app from task manager and not restart again. How can I restart my service on Redmi phone.

I tried to restart service using AlarmManager.

```
private void StartLocationServiceByAlarmManager() {

    Calendar cur_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    cur_cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 50);
    long backgroundServiceUpdateInterval = 0;


       Interval = 3 * 60 * 1000; // xyz

   // stopService(new Intent(this,cl));
    // Background sync service
    Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, cl);
    mServiceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 121,
            mServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            Interval, pintent);
}
```

Comment: Of course it is.  Everything in the process gets killed.  The methods you are referring to *might* result in it being automatically re-started fairly soon, but it will still be killed.  Android simply does not support a way for 3rd party components to run permanently.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I am looking for a solution to restart service again when it is killed on red mi phone. I am able to restart service on all other phones.

Comment: So which solution did you try?  Show you code and explain exactly what it does or doesn't accomplish.

Comment: By using Alarm manager I try to restart service.

Comment: I have added code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

## NOTE : Applicable on Task manager apps killer ONLY

1. Setup MIUM security issues.

For MIUM 7.0 **Security => Autostart => select apps that you want to run in background services => reboot**

For [MIUM 4.0 settings](http://en.miui.com/thread-33826-1-1.html)

2. MainActivity.class (*start services*)

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, Your_IntentServices.class);

       startService(intent);
      }
   }
   ```

   Your_IntentServices.class (*you could extends IntentService*)

   ```
   public class Your_IntentServices extends Service {

       @Override
       public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
           return null;
       }
   ```

   Menifest (*add service*)

   ```
   <manifest>
       <application>
       <service
           android:name=".Your_IntentServices"
           android:exported="false"/>
       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```

[More MIUM Discussion / Other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558866/restarting-killed-stopped-by-task-killers-services-in-android-like-whatsapp/33868617#33868617)