# Restarting killed (stopped by task-killers) services in android like Whatsapp

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, whatsapp

I am working on a app locker which has some background services (to lock apps). I am using Xiaomi Redmi Note 4g for the development. The MIUI has an in-built task manager which can be used to kill running apps. When I kill apps with this, all services, broadcastreceivers and alarmmanagers are getting removed (as expected from a task manager). My requirement is to prevent my background services from getting cleared from task-killers, but if the user navigates to settings and force closes, the service should stop. How do I achieve this?

Btw, I know that its not impossible to achieve this since Whatsapp and Truedialer (some egs) are already doing this on the latest android versions.

My observations from Whatsapp:

- I kill the app from the task manager
- All services in Whatsapp are stopped except for "MessagingService"
- The list view of the running apps show status as "Restarting"
- "AlarmService" service starts up (not sure if MessagingService is starting it or from an AlarmManager)
- After a time lag, all services are up and running

Note: The timer on the MessagingService isn't reset and it still keeps on ticking. But if I force stop the service, its not started again until I manually fire the app.

Similar observations are made for TrueDialer.

I have tried to replicate this with START_STICKY, AlarmManager, BroadcastReceiver, but was unsuccessful. Can someone help me on this? I just want to understand how Whatsapp is achieving this. Feel free to ask if you need more info.

Comment: I am facing  Same Issue IN My application service run properly in all device except Xiaomi Redmi . My service takes upto 5 minutes to restart but i found some thing like whats app ,facebook,instagram application are restart in few seconds,.it shows in Running App..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

**Solution for MIUI 7.0 => Security => Autostart => select Apps that you want to run in background => Reboot**
After reboot your device should able to run your application services in background like other android devices do.

[MIUI 4.0 settings](http://en.miui.com/thread-33826-1-1.html)

[MIUI AutoStart Detailed Description](http://en.miui.com/thread-117992-1-1.html)

Comment: It worked!! Thanks for the solution. I wonder if this is the case for any other devices too.

Comment: still user need to manually change setting. Is there any option to run app like whatsup,skype, instagram,hangout