# AlarmManager using setExact for repeating task stopped working

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, intentservice

I know using setExact for repeating tasks is a bad behavior, but it is a requirement for a mission.

I work on a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 running KitKat and I am using the `setExact` method from the `AlarmManager` in order to schedule an `IntentService` at a **specific** time. I had to abandon `setRepeating` as the documentation said that from SDK 19, it will be **inexact**.

When my `BroadcastReceiver` gets fired up, I start my service and then I re-schedule it with another call to `setExact`, thus mimicking the old `setRepeating` from pre-19.

This happens every **30 minutes**.

Looking at my logs, I can see that my service was triggered from 5PM (when I started the program) to 4AM last night with the **30 minutes interval** as expected and then ... nothing. 
As of writing this post, it still won't be triggered.

I also closed the application since the beginning in order to see if works when the application is not being used. But in Android Studio, the monitor does show that the process is alive.

---

This is the code that will schedule the service the first time:

```
 final Intent activityDataFetcherIntent = new Intent(appContext, ServiceReceiver.class);
 final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appContext, 4334, activityDataFetcherIntent, 0);
 final AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(30), pendingIntent);
```

And finally this is the code from the **BroadcastReceiver**:

```
public final static class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public final void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {   
            final Intent service = new Intent(context, ActivityFetcherService.class);
            context.startService(service);

            // Rescheduling for 30 minutes later
            final Intent activityDataFetcherIntent = new Intent(context, getClass());
            final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 4334, activityDataFetcherIntent, 0);

            final AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(30), pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

This also means that I reschedule the service while it's still running. But all in all the service only runs for 10-15 seconds at most.

Obviously both BroadcastReceiver and Service are declared in the Manifest or else they woud not be fire at all.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: is this your case? please check this accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20745776/4862126

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could it be because I use the same ID all the time ? Should I generate a random id each time in my BroadcastReceiver ?

Comment: Yes, you can use incremental int preference value to avoid getting same ID for multiple instances that you may get in random id generation.

Comment: Got it, I will try it right away and see if it works in the long run. Many thanks for the proposition :)

Comment: @Er.KaushikKajavadara well, it seems to work just fine for the whole day. I'll monitor the logs overnight to see if it holds. Thanks for the tip!